# How to solve "the birthday paradox" in java without using nested loop?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have tried the problem with nested loop, but how can I solve it without using nested loops and within the same class file. The Question is to find the probability of two people having the same birthday in a group. And it should produce the following **output : In a group of 5 people and 10000 simulations, the probability is 2.71%.** Note: using arraylist or hashmap is possible. But I don't know how. Thank you

```
public void process() {
    int groupSize = System.out.getSize();
    int simulationCount = System.out.getCount();

    if (groupSize < 2 || groupSize > 365) {
        System.out.makeAlertToast("Group Size must be in the range 2-365.");
        return;
    }
    if (simulationCount <= 0) {
        System.out.makeAlertToast("Simulation Count must be positive.");
        return;
    }

    double percent = calculate(groupSize, simulationCount);

    // report results
    System.out.println("For a group of " + groupSize + " people, the     percentage");
    System.out.println("of times that two people share the same birthday        is");
    System.out.println(String.format("%.2f%% of the time.", percent));

}


public double calculate(int size, int count) {
    int numTrialSuccesses = 0;

    // Repeat and count.
    for (int n=0; n < count; n++) {
        Random rand = new Random(n);
        // Generate birthdays (random array)
        int[] birthdays = new int [size];
        for (int i=0; i <size; i++) {
            birthdays[i] = rand.nextInt (365);
        }

        // Check if any two match.
        boolean matchExists = false;
        for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < size; j++) {
                if ( (i != j) && (birthdays[i] == birthdays[j]) ) {
                    // Note: musn't forget the i!=j test above!
                    matchExists = true;
                    if (matchExists) break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (matchExists) {
            numTrialSuccesses ++;
        }

    } //end-for-trials

    double prob = ((double) numTrialSuccesses *100)/ (double) count;
    return prob ;

}

}
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Your current approach is to **simulate** those probabilities. You understand that you can simply **compute** them? Given the number of people in a group, you just do some **math** in order to get the exact probability of matching birthdays.

Comment: Just use a `bool[365]` array and index by `day - 1`

Comment: @GhostCat This sounds like a homework problem to me: something like "empirically verify the mathematical analysis of the birthday paradox by simulating groups."

Comment: This may help. https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-the-birthday-paradox/

Comment: In android studio, the coursera auto grader is not able to run it. The grader times out when the solution is inefficient. I should come up with a different solution that does not require nested loops for a single simulation run. This can be accomplished by using different containers  by using arrays or ArrayLists in different ways. How can it be done?

Comment: Use math instead. like @GhostCat said.

Comment: And for the record: I didn't say that this math is **easy** ;-)

Comment: Feel free to mark an answer as helpful :-)

Answer (score 2):

A solution using fancy data structure `HashSet`. As some mentioned in the comments you could use an 365 element array of bools which you switch to true if encountered.

The below is a similar idea. You add each birthday to the set if it does not contain the birthday yet. You increment the counter if the Set *does* contain the birthday. Now you don't need that pesky second iteration so your time complexity goes down to O(n). It goes down to O(n) since a lookup in a set has constant time.

```
public double calculate(int size, int count) {
    int numTrialSuccesses = 0;

    // Repeat and count.
    for (int n=0; n < count; n++) {
     Random rand = new Random(n);

     Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i <size; i++) {
            int bday = rand.nextInt (365);
            Integer bday1 = new Integer(bday);
            if(set.contains(bday1)){
               numTrialSuccesses++;
               break;
             }else{
                 set.add(bday1);
             }
        }
    } //end-for-trials

    double prob = ((double) numTrialSuccesses *100)/ (double) count;
    //like wise comments have noted this is not the probability!!! Just a simulation
    return prob ;

}
```

Comment: I tried running this code, but the value is little away from the actual answer.For 5 people and 10000 simulations, the probability i get is 2.73% but it should be exactly 2.71%.

Comment: I edited to break out of a group once a match is encountered....this sounds like it could be the issue.

Comment: If the numerator is the total groups with *at least* one match and the denominator is total groups then the above code should work now.

Comment: Perfect Solution.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
        int[] birthdays = new int [size];
        for (int i=0; i <size; i++) {
            birthdays[i] = rand.nextInt (365);
        }

        // Check if any two match.
        boolean matchExists = false;
        for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < size; j++) {
                if ( (i != j) && (birthdays[i] == birthdays[j]) ) {
                    // Note: musn't forget the i!=j test above!
                    matchExists = true;
                    if (matchExists) break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (matchExists) {
            numTrialSuccesses ++;
        }
```

can be changed to:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=0; i <size; i++) {
  int day=rand.nextInt (365);
  if(list.contains(day)){
    numTrailSuccesses++;
    break;
  }else{
    list.add(day);
  }
}
```

Comment: No explanations ... no upvotes. Good answers are **more** than just working code!

Comment: What I was going to post, but ArrayList.contains is O(n), so this doesn't actually change the double looping

Comment: Thing is: saying "change this" to "that" ... isn't an explanation. Especially when your code is doing the same thing in the end. You see, List.contains() is not the "same" as Set.contains(). You just put that inner loop in some method call ... but hiding something is not the same as *eliminating* it.

Comment: The question was: "how can I solve it without using nested loops" after that, he mention that he es talking about arraylists or hash, then, you can infer that he is refering to the code of looking for the repetitions, the answer then, is correct, even if you want to make it more complicated that what a First commer in StackOverflow really is asking...

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña  I used the above code, but the autograder still times out. But as far as I see the solution turns out to be perfectly correct (2.71%) when I run it in eclipse and BlueJ. I do not know the problem with autograder.

Answer (score 0):

In java-8,

```
double calculateProbability(int trials, int people) {

    //for trials = 10_000, people = 5
    int timesWithSharedBirthday =  IntStream.range(0,trials)     // Run 10_000 trials
                                            // generate 5 bdays, count distinct ones. Filter out those with 5 distinct
                                            .filter(i -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(people,1,365).distinct().count() != people) 
                                            .count();          // Add up the runs without five distinct bdays.

    return probability = 100.0 * timesWithSharedBirthday / trials;
}
```

I don't know how it will fare with your online grader, but it's fun to practice with streams.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to go beyond primitives with something like a fixed number of birthdays.

Create an array of 365 buckets, and make a note in each bucket of when a birthday hit that date. This allows the use of efficient array operations.

Rather than creating a new array each time, the code below uses `System.arraycopy` to copy a zeroed-out array over the existing one--this gains a bit of performance.

Nevertheless, the performance gain over the `HashSet` example given earlier is modest at best, performing 5 or 6 times faster, but not orders of magnitude faster.
As such, if using `HashSet` and similar tools improves clarity, then go for clarity.

```
  public double calculate(int size, int count) {
    int numTrialSuccesses = 0;
    int[] daysOfYear = new int[365];
    final int[] empty = new int[365];
    // Repeat and count.
    for (int n = 0; n < count; n++) {
      Random rand = new Random(n);

      // Efficiently clear out the array
      System.arraycopy(empty, 0, daysOfYear, 0, 365);

      boolean matchExists = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int birthday = rand.nextInt(365);
        // Compare, then increment, the bucket for the birthday
        if(daysOfYear[birthday]++>0){
          matchExists = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (matchExists) {
        numTrialSuccesses++;
      }
    } //end-for-trials

    double prob = ((double) numTrialSuccesses * 100) / (double) count;
    return prob;
  }
```